# How to disable textarea on valueChange

Tags: tapestry, mixins

I am working with tapestry framework and i have select and textarea. I want to disable the textarea in dependence of which value is chosen in select. Is it necesery to write a mixin or there is some simply way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd just use plain old javascript.

you can include a js resource in your page or component class via @Import.